# Mysql syntax for removing rows with 2 specific duplicate fields?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that contains tagging information, and some of the tag pairs, `relation_id` and `tag_id` are duplicates. Ignoring the other fields, is it possible to select (and eventually delete) rows whose pairs of these fields are redundant?

For example, I have this table: 
[image: phpMyAdmin Screenshot]

and the second row is a duplicate, since it has the same values for `relation_id` and `tag_id` as the previous entry. The third row is fine. The fifth row is a duplicate, and the seventh, eighth, etc.

What's the mySQL syntax for selecting these kinds of duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent mysql to store a combination more then once,
you can use UNIQUE like:

```
ALTER TABLE omeka_taggins ADD UNIQUE(relation_id, tag_id)
```

should prevent adding duplicates to the table,

if you try to do that when there already is duplicates,
you get warnings,
but you can ignore that warning with:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE omeka_taggins ADD UNIQUE(relation_id, tag_id)
```

please backup the table before playing with the ignore keyword,
as its ignore a lot of good warnings

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken it should be a simple delete to remove all the rows that meet a given criteria.

```
 DELETE FROM tags
 WHERE `tag_id`= 'some_value' AND `relation_id`= 'some_value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` and `having` modifiers to find duplicates. Something similar to this:

```
select tag_id, relation_id, count(*) from omeka_taggings group by tag_id,relation_id having count(*)>1
```